# Filling screen Android dont work with S3 S4 screen resolution

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-screen

i am having the following issue, when i use s2 the image takes all the background of the screen(that is what i want), but when i use an s3 or s4, or galaxy note for example, it only fills a quarter of the screen... It only fits well in 480 x 800...I have been with this issue for hours...

Here is the code where it set the params...

```
                LinearLayout lLayout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
                lLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                lLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(((ImageView)mView).getDrawable());
                mlayout.addView(lLayout);
```

If i harcode the layout params to take 1080 x 1980 it works well in s4... but that is not a solution...

Can anyone help me with this issue plis?

Comment: is mlayout a LinearLayout?

Comment: Yes it is a Linear, and mView is a View

Comment: Share your mlayout xml if my answet does not work

Comment: Try using 'Match_Parent' instead. Fill_Parent is deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

after mLayout.addView add

mLayout.forceLayout();

if not work:

mLayout.forceLayout();

mLayout.invalidate();

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LinearLayout lLayout = new LinearLayout(mContext);  
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
lLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(((ImageView)mView).getDrawable());
mlayout.addView(lLayout, params);
```

Also `mlayout` should not have any static size params (or conditional weights to other children) for its root layout.